# Opening documents from MSS2010 takes long

Tags: document

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is slowing the opening of Office documents?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19390/what-is-slowing-the-opening-of-office-documents)

I would like to ask whether someone has experience with documents opened from Sharepoint taking very long time (up to 1 minute, lets say). Word (Excel,...) shows message "Contacting server for information" and nothing happens for some time.
I am not sure whether this is also connected to the following - when opening Explorer view in Sharepoint 2010, it also takes very long, and the user is also prompted for credentials.
We have a single domain, the site is included in Local intranet zone, and the problems mentioned occur even to the site/farm admin.
Help would be appreciated.
Ravie.