# Word 2013 loading documents from a Sharepoint 2013 library very slowly

Tags: 2013, word

I have a weird problem with my SP2013 server and Word 2013. Whenever I try to open a word document from a Sharepoint library, MS Word 2013 on the client computer starts veeery slowly (the "Loading Word" splash screen hangs for more than 2 minutes). After loading the document however, everything works fine. When opening a document from the local drive, Word starts instantly.

I already tried unticking "automatic proxy setting" in Internet Explorer, setting the Web Client Service via registry but nothing has helped.

The strange thing is that all other office doc types (e.g. excel, ppt) are downloaded and opened really quickly. I tried using Office 2007 on an XP machine and Word loads the same file within a second.

The only specific of my environment is, that it is an intranet site with no internet access. It is probably the reason for Office 2013 logging MSOIDSVC errors when opening a doc/xls from Sharepoint. I also discovered some 401 auth errors using Fiddler but these do not seem to slow things down - the same sequence appears with excel files, which load quickly.

Many thanks in advance for any clue.

Comment: I had same issue when I have a lot of data in property bag on the list. I discovered it using Fiddler. Word loads those data each time on each document.

Comment: In my case it is probably something different, these delays occur even in newly created libraries with a basic set of columns and a few files

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly same problem. We resolve our problem creating DNS Zone for microsoft.com , now it works.

You can check this topic
[What is slowing the opening of Office documents?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19390/what-is-slowing-the-opening-of-office-documents)

Answer (score 0):

You say you are using the old .DOC file format. I have experienced the same issue using this old format when there are a lot of links/references in the document. This caused Word to open very slowly because the page index needed to be recalculated.

Does the document contain a lot of references and links?
Or do you use a custom template in word that forces Word to do validation when the document is opened?

Comment: No, it is not the case, it doesn't matter whether doc or docx, there are no links or references int he file. a custom template is not the case as well, I tried it from a clean installed PC.